# Best way for translation with _e

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation

I have this two lines in my code:

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array( 
    'id' => 'plugin_update_notifier', 
    'title' => '<span>' . HEUREKA_FEED_PRO_NOTIFIER_PLUGIN_NAME 
        . ' <span id="ab-updates"> ' 
        . _e('Vynovenie', 'podujatie_heureka') . '</span></span>', 
     'href' => get_admin_url() . 'index.php?page=heureka_feed_pro-plugin-update-notifier' ) );
```

and

```
add_dashboard_page( 
    HEUREKA_FEED_PRO_NOTIFIER_PLUGIN_NAME . ' Plugin Updates', 
    $menu_name . ' <span class="update-plugins count-1"><span class="update-count"> ' . _e("Vynovenie", 'podujatie_heureka') . ' </span></span>', 
    'administrator', 
    'heureka_feed_pro-plugin-update-notifier', 
    'heureka_feed_pro_update_notifier');
```

What' the best way for translation `_e(` ?
It is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the correct function, `_e()` *echoes* the value and you need to *assign* it with the sister function **`__()`**.
See [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

PHP functions [`printf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) and [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) are very useful too:

```
'title' => sprintf(
    '<span>%s <span id="ab-updates"> %s </span></span>',
    HEUREKA_FEED_PRO_NOTIFIER_PLUGIN_NAME,
    __( 'Vynovenie', 'podujatie_heureka' )
),
```

Comment: thank you, this helped me, but can you help me with second part of my code? I tried to solved it, but no luck :( thank you for help